# Linker error with MPLAB X IDE - could not find definition of symbol

Tags: linker-errors, mplab

Am using `MPLAB X IDE`. Using `xc18` compiler and `mplink 5.00`.

I am getting a linker error:

> Error - could not find definition of symbol 'UCONbits' in file
>   './build/default/production/Source/BootPIC18NonJ.o'.

I have added the directories for the relative libraries in the project proprties.

Thing is, there is no reference to `UCONbits` in the file `BootPIC18NonJ.c` or its header.
`UCONbits` is defined in the system header `p18f4550.h.` 
Other `p18f4550.h` definitions can be found in `BootPIC18NonJ.c` such as   `EECON1`

but as I have said, there is no reference to `UCON` or `UCONbits`.

Answer (score 0):

You should include `xc.h` in each source file.

kind regards